# Keep unique values (comma separated) from each column

Tags: text-processing, deduplication

I have a `.tsv` (tab-separated columns) file on a Linux system with the following columns that contain different types of values (strings, numbers) separated by a comma:

```
col1    col2    
.       NS,NS,NS,true,true      
.       12,12,12,13 
1,1,1,2 door,door,1,1
```

I would like to keep the unique values (unfortunately I tried but couldn't). This would be the output:

```
col1 col2   
.    NS,true        
.    12,13  
1,2  door,1
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a Miller variant that splits the value string into an integer-indexed map, then uniquifies it by swapping the map's keys and values (joining the *keys* back into a comma-separated string):

```
mlr --tsv put 'for (k,v in $*) {
  $[k] =  joink(apply(splitnvx(v,","), func(k,v) {return{v:k}}),",")
}' file.tsv
```

Alternatively, in perl5 with help from the [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util) module:

```
perl -MList::Util=uniq -F'\t' -lpe '
  $_ = join "\t", map { join ",", uniq split /,/, $_ } @F
' file.tsv
```

Comment: The mlr --tsv works perfect! What about if I want to the same only on specific columns? Let's say col2 and col3 in a tsv dataset with 100 columns. Many thanks!

Comment: @df_v you can restrict the outer loop to specific columns by key using `mapselect` ex. `for (k,v in mapselect($*,"col2","col3")) { ... }`

Answer (score 6):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to loop over the tab-delimited fields in each input record, split the field's values on commas, add each generated string as a key in a map called `seen`, and finally rewrite the field by joining the keys from the `seen` map using commas as delimiters:

```bash
$ mlr --tsv put 'for (k,v in $*) { seen={}; for (i in splitax(v,",")) { seen[i]=1 } $[k] = joink(seen,",") }' file
col1    col2
.       NS,true
.       12,13
1,2     door,1
```

The Miller `put` expression pretty-printed:

```
for (k, v in $*) {
    seen = {};
    for (i in splitax(v, ",")) {
        seen[i] = 1
    }
    $[k] = joink(seen, ",")
}
```

Adding the split-up values as keys in the map deduplicates them.  The `splitax()` function splits a string on a delimiter into an array without inferring the type of each generated item (they will be strings).  The `joink()` function joins the keys of a map together into a string delimited by the given delimiter.  The values of `k` and `v` in the outer loop are the field names and their values, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.split("\t")  \
                .map: *.split(",").unique.join(",") andthen  \
             .join("\t").put;'   file
```

Linewise non-autoprinting (`-ne`) command-line flags are used. Starting with a `TSV` file, you `split` on tabs, then `map` into each resulting element to again `split` on commas. Here Raku's `unique` routine will remove duplicates (you `join` back again on commas at this point).

A nice feature of the Raku language are what I call  *"connector"* codephrases such as `andthen`, which can simply be thought of as re-loading the return from the LHS into the `$_` topic variable on the RHS. On the RHS the columns are `join`ed back together on tabs and then out`put`.

Sample Input:

```
col1    col2    
.   NS,NS,NS,true,true  
.   12,12,12,13 
1,1,1,2 door,door,1,1
```

Sample Output:

```
col1    col2    
.   NS,true 
.   12,13   
1,2 door,1
```

Note: Raku's `unique` routine takes an `as` named argument (also known in Raku lingo as an *"adverb"*). So if you'd like to compare strings for example, you can write `.unique(as => *.fc)` to compare based upon "foldcase" (i.e. a caseless string comparison).

https://docs.raku.org/routine/unique
https://docs.raku.org/type/Cool#routine_fc
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Comment: Nice! And this one is significantly shorter than the perl5 ones I'm coming up with.

Comment: @terdon if you don't mind cheating with List::Util you could do `perl -MList::Util=uniq -F'\t' -pe '$_ = join "\t", map { join ",", uniq split /,/, $_ } @F' file.tsv`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing something like that, but I tend to avoid using extra modules for one liners since that requires installing the modules and most people who don't live in Perl-land won't be willing to. Still, that's a really neat approach, please go ahead and post it, @steeldriver, it's much nicer than the monstrosity I came up with.

Comment: @terdon it looks like (at least on Debian based systems), List::Util is packaged as part of `libperl5.xx` standard library - so I've posted the solution (along with a Miller variant for fun)

Answer (score 4):

The following `awk` program would do (should work on all moderately recent Awk implementations that support the `delete` operation on arrays<sup>(1)</sup>):

```awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}

{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    {
        n=split($i,sf,",")
        delete seen
        fld=""

        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if (!seen[sf[j]]++)
            {
                fld=fld (fld?",":"") sf[j]
            }
        }
        $i=fld
    }
    print
}
```

Store this as e.g. `dedup.awk` and call it via

```
awk -f dedup.awk input.tsv
```

to act on your input file.

This will set `\t` as input and output field separator. It will then

- iterate over all fields of the line (`for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)`)
- split each field into sub-fields (`sf`) at the `,`
- iterate over all sub-fields and re-assemble the field in a temporary variable `fld`, but only add those sub-field values not yet seen in this field. Keep a record in an array `seen`.
- In the end, assign the re-assembled field `fld` to the current field `$i`
- Print the entire line including all modifications made so far

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Thanks to @EdMorton for the hint that support is rather wide-spread nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a clunky Perl approach:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -le '
%k=%l={}; 
print join("\t", 
  join(",",grep{++$k{$_}==1}split(/,/,$F[0])), 
  join(",",grep{++$l{$_}==1}split(/,/,$F[1]))
)' file.tsv
col1    col2
.   NS,true
.   12,13
1,2 door,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line perl solution that

- Does not assume duplicate values are adjacent (a property exhibited by your sample data, but not exploited by others)
- works on any number of columns

```
$ perl -p -e 's{([^\t\n]+)}{my %u;join ",", grep {!$u{$_}++} split m/,/, $1 }ge' file.tsv
```

If you want sorted order values, add the word `sort` before the word `grep`.

If you want this on files that might have carriage returns (i.e. from MS-Windows), add `\r` after `\n`.